# Find control from html to c# in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have problem that how to get html control id in c# code behind page.??
thanks in advance......

Answer (score 1):

If your control is declared in the markup (like `<asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server"/>`) you can just use autogenerated `myLabel` property in code behind. Otherwise, if the control is created dynamically or declared in a template (for example within `Repeater`) you need to know its parent container and do `container.FindControl("controlID")`.

Comment: no,i have html control like <input> ...how can assess this control in code behind file.???that i m asking.....

Comment: if it has runat="server" attribute defined it will behave exactly like web controls i described

Answer (score 0):

If You have input html control and wish to access its value You can get this on lage load using Page.Request.Params property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params.aspx

Or if You wish to access it fully (for read/write) You have to add runat=server attribute and then (for asp.net 3.5)

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refhtmlcontrols.asp

Here You go:
aspx:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <input type="text" runat="server" id="htmlText" name="htmlText"/>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
</form>
```

cs:

```
...
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            htmlText.Value = "kuku";
        }
...
```